# Is ReuseScope.Request supported on .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, servicestack

We are getting an error on a ServiceStack application (v5.8 running in IIS) were it seems that requests are getting mixed up when executed concurrently.

I've managed to reproduce fairly reliably with a simple console app that does this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(cfg.Emails, email =>
{
    var client = new JsonServiceClient(cfg.ApiBaseUrl);
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    AuthUser(client, email);
    GetUser(client, email);
});
```

`GetUser` returns the authenticated user and checks that it matches the email address it expects.  Firing 4 or 5 requests at a time causes at least one to fail every couple of runs.

The current user is injected into the constructor of the service, using container configuration like:

`container.Register<User>(x => container.Resolve<IDatabaseContext>().GetUser()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);`

IDatabaseContext is also configured to be re-used per-request:

```
container.Register<IDatabaseContext>(x => 
   new DbContext(container.TryResolve<IRequest>())).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

It *appears* that trying to resolve IRequest from the container is unreliable.  I think this simple code inside a service method proves that:

```
var r = _container.Resolve<IRequest>();
var cookie = Request.GetSessionId();
var otherCookie = r.GetSessionId();
if (cookie != otherCookie) throw new Exception("oh noes!");
```

The question is: is this supposed to be supported?  The docs here https://docs.servicestack.net/ioc suggest so (emphasis mine):

> ServiceStack uses a slightly modified version of Funq - which was adopted because of its excellent performance and memory characteristics. ServiceStack’s version of Funq has been enhanced with Expression-based Auto-wiring **and lifetime Request Scope**.

However, searching around has lead to https://forums.servicestack.net/t/reusescope-request/6384 which seems to be saying "Don't use Request scope".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is trying to resolve `IRequest` as an IOC dependency, since it's not dependency that's registered or accessible within the IOC.

`IRequest` is the Request Context that's only available at runtime, typically accessed from `base.Request` in your Services that you'd pass as an argument into your dependencies, not as a dependency injected during its construction.

Whilst Request Scope is supported it's [definitely not recommended](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/hostcontext-resolveservice-idisposable/7809/2?u=mythz) especially for trying to access the HTTP Request Context from a static context which is [disabled by default in .NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793).

Comment: Thanks @mythz - that is good to know.  Expected that to be the answer to be honest, but was hoping for something definitive before we spent a lot of time re-writing things!

Comment: It's interesting that you say IRequest isn't available though, because it works 80% of the time!

Comment: @Simon Maybe your App's registered it somewhere? I've just tried `HostContext.Container.TryResolve<IRequest>()` in a Service in a new .NET Core App and it returns `null` 100% of the time.

Comment: How odd...  we have no explicit registration of IRequest anywhere.  This was an app that was NET 4.7 previously, not sure how that would make a difference though

Comment: OK yes we do register it in the IoC, my mistake. That explains it then at least!  Thanks @mythz